# generate_series for dates - different results from psycopg2 vs. DBeaver on same server

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, dbeaver

Alright, new day, new query, happy life...

```
SELECT dt.dt AS date
FROM generate_series(
   '1986-02-01 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone,
   '2021-01-14 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone,
   '1 mon'::interval) dt(dt);
```

[image: result from dbeaver]

so far so good. now let's get this thing running in a nice script in psycopg2....

```
with connection.cursor() as cur:
    cur.execute(
        "SELECT dt.dt AS date FROM generate_series("
           "'1986-02-01 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone, "
           "'2021-01-14 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone, "
           "'1 mon'::interval) dt(dt)"
    )
    res = cur.fetchall()
print(res[-1][0])
> 2020-12-28 23:00:00+00:00
```

wait... what? why is the last element December the 28th instead of January 1st? Is Santa Clause playing games with me? Time zone should only refer to the server time zone - and it's the same server, I double checked. What am I missing?

Comment: Seems odd to me that the psycopg2 result comes out with `+00:00` instead of `+01:00`...  I'd take a look at [`cur.query`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.query)

Comment: Thank you @cosmic_inquiry. What am I looking for there?

Comment: can't find something different there: `cur.query` -->
`b"SELECT dt.dt AS date FROM generate_series('1986-02-01 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone, '2021-01-14 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone, '1 mon'::interval) dt(dt)"`

Comment: @Michel Müller: Have a look at https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#time-zones-handling

Comment: OK, here's some update on that:
`cur.execute("select '2021-01-14 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone")`
`res = cur.fetchone()`
`print(res[0])` --> `2021-01-13 23:00:00+00:00`

I guess it converts to UTC - fine. I don't see how the result would be off by that much though. it seems like the series gets screwed up from timezone shift - the longer the series, the longer the skew?

Answer (score 1):

timezone conversion on psycopg2 side was definitely the issue. The first rows of the result look like this:

[image]

alas, time gets shifted back to last month in UTC, and then funnily enough it stays on the 28th of the month after the first February.

The solution to my problem was to make the series timezone agnostic:

```
SELECT get_eom(date(dt.dt)) AS date
    FROM generate_series('1986-02-01'::date, 'now'::date, '1 mon'::interval) dt(dt)
```

gives me the result I'd expect from all clients.